# Android 'setText' durante X segundos

Tags: java, android

En mi activity llamo a un `setText`:

```
   tvdato.setText(String.valueOf("BIEN"));
```

Me gustaría saber un método para hacerlo provisional,es decir,que dure durante unos segundos dibujado en pantalla.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer que tu `TextView` sea invisible cuando pase unos segundos con ayuda del **`TimerTask`**:

```
Timer t = new Timer(false);
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
@Override
public void run() {
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              tvdato.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          }
      });
  }
}, 5000); //5000 equivale a 5 segundos (en milisegundos)
```

---

Por otra parte, creo que lo más útil para mostrar un mensaje durante unos segundos en pantalla, es usar un `Toast`:

```
Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"BIEN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```